# Pandas Dataframe How to extract rows of data before a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like,

```
A,B,C
1,2,'Balder'
3,4,'Vasquez'
5,6,'Hatala'
7,8,'Perron'
```

but the dataframe can also be something like,

```
A,B,C
1,2,'Balder'
3,4,'Vasquez'
7,8,'Perron'
```

I want to extract everything before the row,

```
7,8,'Perron'
```

for all kinds of dataframes where the above row can appear anytime. It is dynamic and not appearing at a fixed row number!

I have tried skipping the rows in my dataframe using the skiprows variable but it doesn't help for all cases.

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv',skiprows=)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your index are integer numbers, first find the index of the row that contains your data, then use `loc` to get all rows before that one.

```py
idx = df[(df.A == 7) & (df.B == 8) & (df.C == 'Perron')].iloc[0].name

subset = df.loc[:idx-1]

subset

>>>
A,B,C
1,2,'Balder'
3,4,'Vasquez'
7,8,'Perron'
```

Comment: You don't have to assume they are integers, `loc` works the same with any index value

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution! I was able to make it work for my case easily :)